# Theme Node Add Form for content type created in custom Drupal 9 module

Tags: php, twig, themes, drupal-8, drupal-9

I have built a module in Drupal 9 that creates a content type.

Now I am trying to theme the node/add form.

my_module.module

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function my_module_theme() {
  return [
    'html__node__add__content_type' => [
      'template' => 'html--node--add--content-type',
      'base hook' => 'node'
    ],
  ];
}
```

My html--node--add--content-type.html.twig is recognised and the form renders, BUT all the styling of the site's theme is stripped out.

Within html--node--add--content-type.html.twig, this works to render the form:

```
{{ page }}
```

but this:

```
{{ form }}
```

results in a blank page.

I need to be able to target specific fields, without losing the site's theme css.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Bump.  Keen to get this sorted....